# UIData (UINamingContainer) and Ajax nested partial update

Tags: jsf

I am trying to implement a custom `UIData` component that supports partial (row) update and can be nested. My problem is that in order for the correct child to be rendered I need to know the `UIData` index, so that the clientId of the rendered component is set correctly. Is there a clean way to get it, other than parsing the index from `facesContext.getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds()` or `context.getSubtreeIdsToVisit(this)`?

I am using Mojarra 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `UIData` component is properly implemented/extended, then it's just available by the inherited [`getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) method.

```
int currentRowIndex = getRowIndex();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I was hoping that I could skip creating/restoring the whole tree and just restore/visit the rendered component. i.e. get the rowIndex from the cliendId, then set the rowIndex to that and only process that child. I can now see that it is a very bad idea.